Removing sealed flexi hose
I have used teflon tape and loxeal 58-11 to connect braided flexi hose to cistern. Later I noticed the flexi hose has kink because it was twisted as it was short. I am feeling doubt that hose might brust because of that kink. So I want to replace it with longer one. But the problem is that I have used loxeal 58-11 on thread which has been already more than one week. I am thinking to removed it with wrench. Doing so, does it damage the thread?
